# Is it possible to execute a command after the start of the "ddev-router" (traefik)?

Tags: ddev

It's possible to execute a command on the host after the start of a project with the file ".ddev/config.yaml" of the project like this:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
  - exec-host: the-command
```

But, can we do the same for the "ddev-router" ?

I tried to find the traefik.yaml to add the hooks, but I think it will not works...

Comment: You're doing exactly what I would have recommended; DDEV doesn't have a special hook for when just the router is being started (it's only restarted/started if not already going or if the ports it's bound to change). However, your exec-host  can check to see if what you want to accomplish has already been done, and do it if not. But if you can say more of what you actually are trying to accomplish I might be able to suggest other things.

Comment: Hi rfay, I just need to connect the "ddev-router" to an other docker network. with this command: "docker network connect [my other network] ddev-router"

Comment: Can you just do it on every start as you suggested?

Comment: Yes, but I have several projects, and it make an error/warming of connection (because the network is already connect) for each started or restart project after the 1st one...

Comment: You  can just use `<yourcommand> || true` to avoid the error or warning.

Comment: I finally use the the file "/etc/systemd/system/ddev.service" with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/ddev start --all` and `ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/docker network connect [my other network] ddev-router`. thank you.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why you need to do this anyway...

Comment: It's just because I have another "traefik" (on top of the ddev one) and in order to access the ddev "traefik" I need to be able to access "ddev-router" from the "traefik" (to be able to use: http://ddev-router:10999) as the main one.